# How to render the child route into the router-outlet of the parent`s parent

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

AngularJS 1.x ui-router has the extreme flexible concept of viewports. They seem to me like named routes but offer much more flexibility.

The routes with `viewports` are not divided into something like `primary/aux` routes. They are just put anywhere in the html with the ui-view and you can reference them by viewport name from your states/routes.

Now with the new angular 2 router 3 by viktor savkin I can not find that flexibility because the `<router-outlet>` is directly put to the component, so it seems bound to it.

Maybe my approach is too ui-router like...

Although I know of the angular ui-router for ng2 I do not want to use it:

I have created some sketches (with typos in the url sadly, but I lost the original sketch somehow...)that you understand more what I wanna achieve:

When I am on the state/url /projects/1  - which would be a componentless route with the angular router 3 alpha... - and click the open button of the project then the child meetings for this project are rendered into

I am jumping from one error to the other like:

```
- can not read data annotations of undefined
- can not find primary outled
- can not find any matching route...
```

This is a pretty mess to setup this common scenario.

One of the things I tried:

```
  { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsRootComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: ProjectsListComponent },
      { path: 'create', component: ProjectsCreateComponent },
      { path: ':id', children:[ // componentless route
           { path: 'meetings',  component: MeetingsListComponent},
      ]}
    ]
  },
```

I would be glad about any help on this else I try the ui-router which offers an easier and more obvious concept at first sight.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The router in RC.4 has limited support for aux routes. I haven't seen any mention of adding components to `<router-outlet>` of parent components so far though.

Comment: if that situation will not change then there will be another router 4 :P Ok then I try Chris ui-router. Seems the ngrx router: https://github.com/ngrx/router/blob/master/docs/overview/route.md has multiple named components which seems to work like ui-router viewports and do not need a primary router-outlet which is a bad limitation IMHO.

Comment: It seems even that router is dead... https://github.com/ngrx/router/blob/master/docs/overview/migration.md

Comment: I don't know about it being dead but the Angular-included routet was modeled a lot like the ngrx. No point in maintaining 2 similar routers.

Comment: Sure, but the ngrx was long time before on the market. No need for viktor to show his muscles... I decided to use reactjs and I am happy nothing breaks :-)

Comment: @Elisabeth well done in forecasting... ngrx is really deprecated now!