# How to render a grandchild view into the same router-outlet as the first child?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This is a follow up question to this:
[Angular 2 how does auxiliary routes work in 2.1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124618/angular-2-how-does-auxiliary-routes-work-in-2-1-0/40125619?noredirect=1#comment67522511_40125619)

I also tried looking at this but it doesn't really shed any light on the issue: [How to render the child route into the router-outlet of the parent`s parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192020/how-to-render-the-child-route-into-the-router-outlet-of-the-parents-parent)

If I have a parent route `/admin` which has a `<router-outlet name="admin"></router-outlet>` which looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminAreaComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: '../pages/+login/login.module#LoginModule',
    outlet: 'admin'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: '../pages/+dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
    outlet: 'admin'
  }
];
```

I would access the dashboard via `/admin(admin:dashboard)`, but now I need to render a child view of `dashboard` into the same `router-outlet` as the dashboard, which is `admin`. That view looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'brands',
    loadChildren: '../pages/+brands/brands.module#BrandsModule',
    outlet: 'admin'
  }
];
```

However, when I try to access this route via `/admin(admin:dashboard/brands)` I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin'
```

I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong in the route config.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'brands',
            loadChildren: '../pages/+brands/brands.module#BrandsModule'
        }
    ]
  }  
];
```

and `/admin/(admin:dashboard//brands)`

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr for this? I was forced to take a different direction but if this works I'll use this instead.

Comment: I don't know how to use loadChildren with plnkr... here my test git repo where I tryed: https://github.com/fabriziodebortoli/dynamic-routing

Answer (score 0):

This might sound crazy, but why not make `dashboard` a child module of `admin`?

Comment: It is a child module of admin.